# Algorithm for Determining Mobile Base Positioning Given End Effector Pose

Tags: mobile-robot, inverse-kinematics

I have a 6 DOF arm robot with a mobile base, and a given x/y/z/quaternion vector that the end effector must match. I am to determine the most optimal position of the mobile base such that an IK solution for the arm can be constructed from the end effector vector. I already have an IK method for the arm alone, but not one that includes the mobile base.

Not to mention, there is a collision aspect to this too. There is collision that the arm must avoid around the vector, which can easily be filtered with my simulator, but is just something that must be considered. Could anybody point out any algorithms that could possibly help? Thank you for your time.

Comment: What are your optimality criteria for the base position?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add three joints to the kinematic chain. The 6 Dof of your arm are preceeded by two prismatic and one revolute joint representing the mobile base. The resulting 9 dof chain forms a redundant manipulator. Now it depends on how you define optimality as to which ik is derived. You can look up Orocos Kdl for starters. Their chain ik solver is  initialized with a random configuration. Simply repeat the process of calculating the ik until your cost yields an acceptable level. Its somewhat brute force but should be straight forward to implement.

Answer (score 0):

If you have acces to academic sources (google scholar), relevant publications are from Vahrenkamp, Stulp and Zacharias.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Sirks. Thanks for your answer but we are looking for comprehensive answers that provide some explanation and context. Very short answers cannot do this, so please edit your answer to explain why it is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

Comment: In addition to what Mark Booth stated, if you can provide references, then you should.